# i need to change a frame's source accoring to champion hovered

Tags: jquery, html, css

so I have an unordered list of champions, and each of them have a link in them, so i want my frame's src to change to that champ's page if he is being hovered on, I currently have this jscript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ifunc() {
// Declare variables
var iframe, ul, li, a, i, div, br;
ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
iframe = document.getElementById('jaiframe')
// Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (li.is(":hovered") {
        iframe.src = "champs/" + li[i] + ".html"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and this is one of my unordered list's code, they are all with the same structure tho,

```
<li style="text-align: right;"><div class="col-md-10"></div><a href="champs/Aatrox.html" class="champ"><div class="col-md-1" id="champ" >
              <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/leagueoflegends/images/c/cc/AatroxSquare.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/48?cb=20160417012601">
              </div><div class="col-md-1" id="champ" >Aatrox</div></a></li>
```

I've tried searching for an answer but couldn't, what am I doing wrong? btw I called the function in the beginning of the unordered list

```
<ul id="myUL" onmouseover="ifunc()" class="pull-left" style="padding-top: 60px;margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 100px;height: 100%"> <!-- List of champions -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically - you should is the `is(":hover")` (and not `is(":hovered")`), but it will be much better to just run your function once an `li` element is hovered:

```
$('ul#myUL li').hover(function() {
  $('#jaiframe').attr('src', $(this).find('a').attr('href'));
});
```

The above code will make sure that every time you `hover` an `li` element that is inside your `ul#myUL` - the `src` attribute of the `iframe` will be set to the value of the 'href' attribute of the `a` element inside the `li` you just hovered.

Comment: note if only one function argument for `hover()` will run for both mouseeneter and mouseleave

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for that info! because the `mouseleave` will happen before the next `mouseenter` (on the next `li` hover) it will be ok. If it wasn't the case I would use `mouseenter` instead of `hover`.

Comment: will still cause a src change needlessly though

Comment: As far as I know - a "change" that doesn't change has no effect. Am I wrong here?

Comment: don't think so...not 100% sure though and may depend on browser